# How to use phonegap sqlite plugin in windows phone

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, sqlite, windows-phone

I made a dictionary application in android using phonegap. Its working fine and tring to port the project to windows phone. I'm using [Cordova-WP-SqlitePlugin](https://github.com/marcucio/Cordova-WP-SqlitePlugin) plugin.

I included the .cs files in my Plugins folder and added Community.CsharpSqlite.WinPhone.dll as a Reference, but still not working. How should i actually use the plugin to access db?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use phonegap 2.7 or lower (newer wont work)
2. copy .js and .cs files (fist into js folder, latter into plugins folder)
3. add  to your config.xml
4. add  to index.html
5. add the shipped Community.CSharpSQlite.WinPhone as a Reference by right-clicking on References in your solution explorer

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same thing here, but I cannot find the Community.CSharpSQlite.WinPhone is it a dll where can i download it? how to I add it as a reference to my project

Comment: download it here.

https://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/downloads/detail?name=csharp-sqlite_3_7_7_1_71.zip&can=2&q=